# Is there a function in Google big query to find the first date and last date of the ISO Week number / Week number of a calendar year?

Tags: google-bigquery

Let us assume a calendar week.

The week number is 02 of 2020.

I am looking for ways to find the beginning and end dates of the week.
Any pointers to built in function or any other approaches will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a direct way, but with existing [date functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#supported_format_elements_for_date), it is super easy to build a look up table which you can query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE day_of_week_table AS
SELECT
  date,
  EXTRACT(ISOYEAR FROM date) AS isoyear,
  EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM date) AS isoweek,
  EXTRACT(WEEK FROM date) AS week,
  EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM date) AS dayOfWeek
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-1-1', '2021-1-1')) AS date
ORDER BY date;
```

Paste first a few rows of this table

```
|    date    | isoyear | isoweek | week | dayOfWeek |
+------------+---------+---------+------+-----------+
| 2020-01-01 |    2020 |       1 |    0 |         4 |
| 2020-01-02 |    2020 |       1 |    0 |         5 |
| 2020-01-03 |    2020 |       1 |    0 |         6 |
| 2020-01-04 |    2020 |       1 |    0 |         7 |
| 2020-01-05 |    2020 |       1 |    1 |         1 |
| 2020-01-06 |    2020 |       2 |    1 |         2 |
| 2020-01-07 |    2020 |       2 |    1 |         3 |
| 2020-01-08 |    2020 |       2 |    1 |         4 |
| 2020-01-09 |    2020 |       2 |    1 |         5 |
| 2020-01-10 |    2020 |       2 |    1 |         6 |
| 2020-01-11 |    2020 |       2 |    1 |         7 |
```